# In 12.04/12.10, what calls the precise/quantal-wallpapers.xml files?

Tags: scripts, configuration, startup

I'm having a hard time sorting out what script or program calls the precise-wallpapers.xml or quantal-wallpapers.xml?  After upgrading to 12.10, my wallpaper selection is still the precise-wallpapers.xml, though the quantal xml file and all the wallpaper files exist in usr/share/backgrounds directory.

Related, certainly there must be a prober script similar in concept to the 30-os-prober script for grub for creating those .xml files, right?

Answer (score 0):

The `Appearance` module of gnome-control-center is what loads the XML files in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/` to get a list of installed wallpapers. It always loads all of the xml files in this directory.

There is no script similar to the grub thing for these XML files. The XML files are static and included in packages. If you still have the `precise-wallpapers.xml` file there, then you still have the `ubuntu-wallpapers-precise` package installed after an upgrade. If you've ever altered the settings by choosing a different image as your background, then upgrading will not automatically cause the background to change to the new default.